# Xcode 6: Can't get App ID and Bundle Identifier to Match

Tags: ios, xcode, app-id, bundle-identifier

I cloned an existing target to create an in-house development/testing version client specific version of our App.  Everything works for the client specific versions, but I can't get the App ID from Apple's Developer Portal to match the Bundle Identifier Xcode creates.

The in-house product is called "Product Name" which produces the expected App ID of "com.company.Product-Name" and Xcode creates the matching "com.company.Product-Name" bundle identifier.

We call the in-house Dev product "Product Name Dev" and the Apple Developer Portal create the App ID of: "com.company.Product-Name.Dev" -- Which is fine; however, I cannot come-up with text to put in the "Product Name" under "Build Settings" to duplicate "com.company.Product-Name.Dev" The following:  "Product Name Dev", "Product Name.Dev", "Product-Name Dev" and "Product-Name.Dev" all produce the bundle identifier "com.company.Product-Name-Dev"

Trying to get the Developer Portal to create an App ID of "com.company.Product-Name-Dev" fails because the portal won't allow -'s or .'s in the Application Name and it auto-generates the App ID

I know I can hand-jam it to match, or add a "REAL_PRODUCT_NAME" as a User Defined Build Setting, but it seems like they should match and I'm worried about problems I might be introducing by not letting automatic stuff happen automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this is the "most correct" answer, but what I did was quit Xcode and manually edited the .plist file so that ${PRODUCT_NAME} was used consistently and the file didn't have any "hard coded" strings.